# Isomorphic Javascript Routes with React-Route vs REST API Routes

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have been studying react/flux/react-router and how pre-rendering virtual DOM in server happens. Calling `Router.run()` and `renderToString` in the server will take care of pre-rendering the page in the server and lazily loading and downloading the rest of .js files to the client. React-router deals with *UI URLs* in any scenario (either client or server). This is not necessarily the same as *REST API URLs* of the server.

What is the best practice to add routes functionality If I want to use the backend for a native app with REST features as well. should I have a complete set of routes definitions for express.js and re-define all the routes in react-routes as well?

React routes are not necessarily similar to express routes (can have more or less route patterns). So replicating route definitions seem inevitable. Is that correct? even [this](http://dmitrirabinowitz.azurewebsites.net/2015/02/13/getting-started-with-fluxible/) example seems to be doing the same thing.

I was hoping to find a way to reuse routes definition or something more DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to duplicate routes on a client and server. See flux examples from Yahoo: https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/tree/master/react-router

Then, just specify API request before the react router on the server. E.g.:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();

// Static files
server.use('/assets', express.static('src/assets'));
server.use('/build', express.static('build'));

// Declare API handling:
require('apiRouting')(server);

// Decalre react-router handling
require('./routing.jsx')(server);

// In the apiRouting.js:
module.exports = function (server) {
    server.get('/api/methodA', function (req, res) {
        // body...
    });
    server.get('/api/methodB', function (req, res) {
        // body...
    });
};
```

Comment: Take a look at yahoo's todo example. They seem to be having as a mock up front end [array](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/blob/master/todo/services/todo.js) of todos, and they pretend api calls through random delays. But they don't say how they eventually do REST API call to which REST routes.

In your example, you are essentially defining '/api/methodA' '/api/methodB' in apiRouting.js. This is your rest API and returns jsons (correct?). You have to redefine routes (URLs) in react-routing in './routing.jsx' again (to tell react which react components to render when).

Comment: So you define a set of ./api routes in the server to give out jsons (database calls and server stuff) and you define normal routes (without ./api) to render react components in server and later in client.

Comment: You can export single module with route names and use it in both server and client. This way you avoid duplicate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's a library that makes it so you can build your APIs in an isomorphic fashion, and re-use it in the client and server without bloating or breaking the bundle. This is what we're currently using in a big single-page application.

It's called Isomorphine, and you can find it here: https://github.com/d-oliveros/isomorphine.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.